# python class definition problrm

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

this my first python code i am trying to connect to a database , i defined a class called Database in a python file called mysqlConnection.py

but when i run the code i get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mysqlConnection.py", line 3, in <module>
    class Database:
  File "mysqlConnection.py", line 27, in Database
    db = Database()
```

my code is :

```
import MySQLdb

class Database:
        host = "localhost"
        user = "root"
        passwd = "root"
        db = "pitest"

        def __init__(self):
                self.connection = MySQLdb.connect( host = self.host,
                                                   user = self.user,
                                                   passwd = self.passwd,
                                                   db = self.db)
        def query(self, q):
                cursor = self.connection.cursor( MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor )
                cursor.execute(q)

                return cursor.fetchall()

        def __del__(self):
                self.connection.close()




        if __name__ == '__main__':
                db = Database()

                q = "DELETE FROM users"
                db.query(q)

                q = """
                INSERT INTO users (title, fname, sname, age, email)
                VALUES ('A', 'Z', 'BIG Z', '20', 'raspberrypi@example.com'),
               ('B', 'X', 'BIG X', '30', 'raspberrypi@example.com'),
               ('C', 'Y', 'BIG Y', '24', 'raspberrypi@example.com'),
               ('A', 'W', 'BIG W', '29', 'raspberrypi@example.com')
                """
                db.query(q)
                q = """
                SELECT * FROM users WHERE title = 'A'
                """

                allreturnedusers = db.query(q)

                for user in allreturnedusers:
                        print "Found: %s " % user['fname']
```

can any one help me please ?

Comment: can you show the full error message?

Comment: The indentation is wrong starting at `if __name__ == '__main__':`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is improperly indented starting at the line

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

Comment: you mean i should re indented  if __name__ == '__main__': ?
or what is under it ?

Comment: `if __name__ == '__main__'` and (of course) the code under it shouldn't be part of the database class.